# Importing exif-js library Uncaught ReferenceError: EXIF is not defined error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, exif-js

I am using vue in a rails application and am trying to import the [exif-js library](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) into my script in order to access the global EXIF variable to use as such

```
var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(this.result));
```

I have downloaded the package by following these [yarn instruction](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/exif-js).

```
yarn add exif-js -- save
```

I realize I need to use the javascript [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) to include it into my scripts and have tried

```
<script>
   import EXIF from 'exif-js'

    previewPhoto() {
      var reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = () => {        
        var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(this.result));
    }

</script>
```

and other variances such as `import 'exif-js'`, however I keep getting  `Uncaught ReferenceError: EXIF is not defined` error. How do I successfully import the library so that I can use it in my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in a CommonJS way:

```
<script>
  var EXIF = require('exif-js');
  previewPhoto() {
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = () => {        
      var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(this.result));
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`import` (if you look carefully at the top of the MDN article you linked) is not currently supported natively by most/all browsers are this point in time, although browsers are working towards native es6 module support.  As a result, if you are ***not*** using webpack or another build tool, you need to use a different approach.

You can drop the `exif-js` library into your app via script tag in the head of your root html doc:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/exif-js@2.2.1"></script>
```

Once the file is parsed, a global `EXIF` variable will be available and you can run your code:

```
previewPhoto() {
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = () => {        
        var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(this.result));
}
```

Note that the fat arrow function `() =>` will also have [limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: How do you make this work with webpack? I am getting the same error in laravel 5.5